# In Journey Builder, can I reference journey B's data inside journey A?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I'm looking to build two journeys, A and B. Inside A, I'd like to create a split where I check if user entered B between when they entered A and now. If they have, I need to check that their entry event for B had a particular property (e.g. `amount` was more than $500). If the check fails, I want to exit the user from A. Each journey is initiated by API call to /interaction/v1/events.

I'm relatively new to SFMC, but I understand that the journey entry-event tables are just data extensions, so it seems like it should be possible to do this kind of cross-referencing, but I can't figure out how. Is this even possible? If so, how can I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**
Assuming you have non-null able field (let's say Contact ID) on both the API data extensions. You can add the Journey B data extension into Contact designer. Also you can add an AND condition to check if the amount is more than $500.

> Go to Audience Builder > Contact Builder > Contact Designer > Create
>   an attribute group >Give a name to it > Add the journey B data
>   extension  > Map the contact key with contact ID

Once you are done with this, Go to Journey Builder A decision split, drag & drop the contact ID in journey data and check on compare attribute and drag & drop the contact ID from the contact data on the attribute group.

Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_attribute_comparison.htm&type=5

**Approach 2:** If you don't have an non-nullable field in those data extensions. Then you can add a new Boolean field in Journey A called "Is Present in Journey B" and write a SQL query

```
Select A.ContactID, 
Case when A.ContactID IN (B.ContactID from [Journey B] as B where B.amount > 500) 
Then '1' 
else '0' 
End as [Is Present in Journey B]
from [Journey A] as A
```

You can add Journey A in contact builder > data designer and check in the decision split if the "Is Present in Journey B" = True and accordingly you can set up other stuff.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This works perfectly—thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome @Rohan !